# How to find arguments of multivariable function for known local extrema?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

There is the function of multiple variables ($r$ is the main one):

$U(r) = U_{0}e^{-\alpha(r-(1+\delta))}(e^{-\alpha(r-(1+\delta))}-2)$ + $16L^2\left(\frac{f}{\pi}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}e^{-\frac{\pi(r-1)}{L}}\left(1-\frac{1}{2}n_{c}k\frac{2L-r+1}{1+2L}\right)^{-\frac{3}{2}}$

All variables are independent.
For some sets of variables $(\alpha, \delta, L, f, k, n_{c}, U_{0})$ the function has minimum and maximum at the interval $1 < r < 2$ (pic related)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjCLe.jpg). Call them $U_{w}$ -- local minimum  and $U_{b}$ -- local maximum.

Of course, it is easy to find $U_{w}$ and $U_{b}$ for the known set $(\alpha, \delta, L, f, k, n_{c}, U_{0})$. The **reverse problem** is how to find ALL such sets $(\alpha, \delta, L, f, k, n_{c}, U_{0})$ corresponding to the fixed $U_{w}$ and $U_{b}$ pair.

The analytical solution seems impossible, because the equation $\frac{dU}{dr} = 0$ is unsolvable for $r$. I have also tried to expand exponents to Taylor series, but the obtained formula is too complex to use it actually and it's accuracy is unknown.

The numerical solution may be the way, but how to be sure that it found all sets and there are no other solutions?